# Disable Angular2 multiselect dropdown option on load

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, angular7, multi-select, disable

I want to disable and keep an option checked using angular2-multiselect. I tried using disabled but either I am not using it properly or it is not working on my code.

Here it is:

```
     <div class="col-md-2">
                      <div class="form-group  input-group-sm">
                        <label for="dataPoint">Data Point</label>
                        <angular2-multiselect required style="display: block;" [data]="dataPointList" [(ngModel)]="dataPointId" name="dataPoint" 
[disabled]="isDisabled"
                          [settings]="dataPointSettings" (ngModelChange)="onDataPoint($event)" (onDeSelect)="OnItemDeSelect($event)"  ></angular2-multiselect>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

TS:

```
isDisabled: any;
ngOnInit() {
 for (var ind = 0; ind < this.dataPointList.length; ind++) {
            if (this.dataPointList[ind].dataPointName === 'Rating') {  
              isDisabled = true;
            }
        }
} // option with rating value needs to be disabled
```

Basically I want same as this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8zvhqf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts but for template driven form in angular.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the disabled property at the option level

```
ngOnInit() {
    for (var ind = 0; ind < this.dataPointList.length; ind++) {
        if (this.dataPointList[ind].dataPointName === 'Rating') {
            this.dataPointList[ind].disabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```